# SMART status bad and good

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, boot, smart

when I start up my Pc, I usually get the S.M.A.R.T status bad : Backup and replace. I know what the warning is, but I'm not sure "who" to trust:

CrystalDiskInfo says status is Good (at 87% though). To me it seems like weird stuff started to happen after installing Windows 10. I did a clean install.

However, it does boot up when i put a flash-drive with windows10 (UEFI) in the usb. It starts loading and I guess it recovers some corrupt boot files or whatnot.

Anyone have similar experience and/or can give advice? Could the error on boot be wrong somehow?

-- EDIT

I did as suggested, and found the utility diag tool for my exact drive (OCZ-ARC100). Here is an image that shows the stats I get:
[OCZ Drive - Diagnostics image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYKyQ.jpg)

Comment: Please post more detailed information from CrystalDiskInfo.

Comment: Will do, when I get back home.

Comment: Get HD Tune and post a screenshot from the health tab.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to see what the health of unit is to run a diagnostics test, which you did, but unfortunately I won't be able to tell anything for sure until I take a look at the results, so if possible, upload a screenshot.

ALong with the third party apps I'd suggest to check if such tool is available in the manufacturers website and use it as well because it will be tuned to the specific firmware of the hard disk and will give you results from another source as well. For instance, WD has [Data Lifeguard Diagnostics](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=idgt1j).

Let me know how it went.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even think of finding the exact tool. Just did, and edited original post with a couple of screen-grabs.

Comment: Any thoughts about it?

Comment: You're welcome, mate! I can't see anything wrong with the unit and the results are looking pretty good. One thing I'd suggest though is to plug the SSD in your SATA III port though because that way it will be able to perform faster. :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Yeah, I'll plug it back there (changed ports while testing for broken cable or whatnot). How come I get the error though? I haven't reset my PC since I got it back up again, but I'd like to know what the heck is going on. Most times I get this error and even BIOS can't find the drive. But, like I said, it can find it either randomly or when I plug in windows UEFI boot flashdrive...  Is it the motherboard, or perhaps some Windows 10 face-palm bug?